# WCF async call return a 10054 error: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-mobile

I have a WCF consumed by a **Windows Mobile 5.0 or above** application with **.NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2** and **C#**.

When the application consume a asynchronous "method" it throws that message. This is also the stackTrace of inner exception:

```
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveNoCheck()
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive()
at System.Net.Connection.Read()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.fillBuffer()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.getLine()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.parseResponse()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.startReceiving()
at System.Net.Connection.startReceiving()
at WorkItem.doWork()
at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

The message from the exception is:

"Unable to read data from the transport connection."

And its stackTrace is:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.finishGetResponse()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doAsyncInvoke()
at WorkItem.doWork()
at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

What's happening?

If you need more details tell me!

**Update**:

I have two computers and on both the same error happens. One of then is a Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, and the other is a Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit. Maybe it is something releated to code...

Thank you.

Comment: Based on the link you posted in the comment, it sounds like maybe your client that is sending the connection request is sending too many too fast?  Is your code trying to make more than one connection?  If it fails to connect are you trying again?  Are you using a port that is reserved?  Are any of your socket requests getting processed at all?

What does your listener code look like?  Does it loop, wait for responses, or just stop?  What about the client?  Are you using any type of control code to close the connection or just forcing it shut.

Is this using WCF? or pure Net Sockets?

Comment: One other question since you say it's Aysnc.  Does it work at all in a straight call, Non-Async?

Comment: Now, it works and I don't change anything. There is an error and I'm going to find it.

Comment: And now, it doesn't work. And I don't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/) had an answer that worked for me, using three parts:

1. Disable KeepAlive

   webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
2. Set ProtocolVersion to Version10

   webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
3. Limiting the number of service points (ServicePoint is null until GetResponse() is called)

   webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;

Answer (score 0):

For socket exceptions like this, we usually need to capture network traffic using Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor to troubleshoot. Only when such information is available we can say what happens on the wire (or wireless).

Comment: Do you need that information? Would you like to show you that information?

Comment: Sorry, no. Analyzing such data takes time :) If you are not familiar with such analysis, you may contact Microsoft support team via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: I don't think is a network problem because I have two computers and on both happens the same error.

Comment: Ok, I added this key to registry: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ DWORD SynAttackProtect 00000000" and it works! But I'm going to delete it because it's not safe. I've found it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189083%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the interval between calls is longer than the HTTP keep-alive timeout and/or some intervening NAT session timeout.  The server or middlebox closes the connection, and the client doesn't notice until it tries to reuse the connection.  It's appropriate to retry in this case.